# Simple jquery ajax call to controller: what is causing 500 Internal server error?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I know that there are a lot of similar questions here on SO, but none of the ones I have read could help me solve my problem.

I have a drop down list with several items to choose from, the change of selection should trigger a method call in the controller `OnItemSelectedChange(string itemName)`

**View (~/Home/Views/Index.cshtml)**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, new 
SelectList(@Model.Items), new { onchange = "SelectedItemChanged(this);" })
```

**jquery**

```
function SelectedItemChanged(selectObj) {
        itemName = selectObj.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/OnSelectedItemChanged/?itemName=' + itemName,
        }).done(function () {
            alert('Modified item');
        });
    }
```

**Controller's action (~/Controllers/HomeController)**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnSelectedItemChanged(string itemName)
{
    // do stuff 
    return View(new MyModel {...});
}
```

The javascript is being called fine, but `POST Home/OnSelectedItemChanged?itemName=item3` returns "500 Internal Server Error".

I believe the problem is in the routing to the controller method, yet I thought MVC auto-populated the parameters

Comment: Are you sure its not that you're providing `itemName` on the querystring but, being a `POST`, it should be in the body?

Comment: That's a good point, I'm very new to all this, was not aware that a POST did not contain data in the url. Could changing to a GET be the solution then? I'll give that  a try.

Comment: @Jamiec I've tried `type: 'POST', url: '/Home/OnSelectedItemChanged', data: { 'itemName': itemName }`. I get the same error (500). If I replace the POST with a GET I get a 404 not found...

Comment: And if you debug the server what is the cause of the 500 error? (ie, put a breakpoint at the start of the `OnSelectedItemChanged` method and step through)

Comment: Have you tried typing in this URL manually to see if it is correct.

Comment: You should log all server side errors so they don't get lost.

Comment: @Jamiec the controller's method does not get called. Typing in the URL manually leads to an HTTP 404 error... how would I log server side errors?

Comment: It depends what platform you're targetting - netcore or full.net - plenty of info online about enabling logging

Comment: Sounds like your URL is incorrect? Try Using a Url.Action helper to generate it for you and inject that into your JS. As for errors, even if you aren't logging errors, if you step through your code with your debugger it should halt on any exceptions. Also looking in the "response" tab of the ajax request in your browser's network tab might have some more details about the error (e.g. it might have tried to return a HTML error page containing a stack trace, depending on your app's settings, whether you're running it locally etc)

Comment: @ADyson, I've switched to to `url:'@Url.Action("OnSelectedItemChanged","Home")'` helper but the result is the same :( I'll log server side errors as @mason suggested and will try to make sense of all this

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a silly mistake, obviously. Thanks @ADyson in the comments for suggesting to have a look at the "response" tab of the ajax request, which stated "the View 'OnSelectedItemChanged' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/OnSelectedItemChanged.aspx
~/Views/Home/OnSelectedItemChanged.ascx [...]"

When I return my View in my controller, I should specify the view name so that the proper location is searched i.e. changing:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnSelectedItemChanged(string itemName)
{
    // do stuff 
    return View(new MyModel {...});
}
```

into

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnSelectedItemChanged(string itemName)
{
    // do stuff 
    return View("Index", new MyModel {...});
}
```